# How to acess API rest/views using token or login?

Tags: 8

I have a Drupal 8 website. I need to access the list of articles using www.myexample.com/rest/views/articles.

I could get the token using `curl --header "Content-type: application/json" -b cookies.tt --request POST "https://www.myexample.com/user/login?_format=json" --data '{"name":"myname", "pass":"mypassword"}'`.

How do I use cUrl to pass the token or user/pass and get 'rest/views/articles' in JSON format?

I tried `curl --header 'authorization: Bearer {D12G7AajU9NdUAb260zqwCimfdddR1Krg5}' --url https://www.myexample/rest/views/artigos/format?_format=json`, 
but it returns an error.

**UPDATE**

I follow the @Ismail Cherri suggestion, seems a progress in the question but give me back :

```
"message":"The used authentication method is not allowed on this route."
```

In drupal website the config :

/entity/view/{view}
is set to :

```
GET
formats: hal_json, json
authentication: basic_auth
```

and 
/entity/entity_view_mode/{entity_view_mode}
is set to :

```
GET
formats: hal_json, json
authentication: basic_auth
```

anyone could help?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: At /user/login you start a loggedin session and receive csrf token - this token needs for a POST/PATCH (with header key 'X-CSRF-Token') and this not eliminate the needs of Authorization - it is not needed for GET, I would recommend you to check JWT or api_key modules for D8 to use for authorization. Of course, a cookie authentication is the easiest way for an authorized request, but it is tricky to get a cookie (or data to create a cookie) if your frontend is not served from the address where is your rest point.

Comment: If you're just using basic_auth and nothing else, then you need to perform a basic auth login for every request you make. If you also enable cookie auth then you can use the cookie for subsequent requests after creating it with a call to user/login.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, does your endpoint require authentication to begin with? 
If yes, then use this https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/3-post-for-creating-content-entities as a guide though it is for a POST request.

---

UPDATE
You need to know which authentication method are you using, e.g. basic_auth, cookie, Oauth, etc?
According to the method, you should formulate your request. The use of X-CSRF-Token is for Cookie Authentication.
It might be in your case that you successfully got the token, but you're using it on an endpoint which requires Basic Auth.
As I see in your posted REST configuration, you're actually using Basic Auth, thus your request should look something like this:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url http://example.com/entity/view/{view} \
  --header 'authorization: Basic HASH_HERE' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Your answer has been very usefull therefore this method give me back another message:  "The used authentication method is not allowed on this route." in drupal config rules I set to allow, in navigator works well. Could you help me one more time ?

Comment: Sure no problem, can you update your question to reflect the current state. Please add the update below your current questions so that others can follow along. Thanks :)

Comment: Done! Could you follow your explanation?